# Max date among records and across tables - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, max

I tried max to provide in table format but it seem not good in StackOver, so attaching snapshot of the 2 tables.  [image]Apologize about the formatting.

SQL Server 2012

```
**MS Table**            
**mId   tdId    name                    dueDate**
1   1   **forecastedDate**              1/1/2015
2   1   **hypercareDate**               11/30/2016
3   1   LOE 1                       7/4/2016
4   1   LOE 2                       7/4/2016
5   1   demo for yy test            10/15/2016
6   1   Implementation – testing    7/4/2016
7   1   Phased Rollout – final      7/4/2016
8   2   forecastedDate              1/7/2016
9   2   hypercareDate               11/12/2016
10  2   domain - Forte              NULL
11  2   Fortis completion           1/1/2016
12  2   Certification               NULL
13  2   Implementation              7/4/2016
-----------------------------------------------

**MSRevised**   
**mId   revisedDate**
1   1/5/2015
1   1/8/2015
3   3/25/2017
2   2/1/2016
2   12/30/2016
3   4/28/2016
4   4/28/2016
5   10/1/2016
6   7/28/2016
7   7/28/2016
8   4/28/2016
9   8/4/2016
9   5/28/2016
11  10/4/2016
11  10/5/2016
13  11/1/2016
----------------------------------------
```

The required output is
1. Will be passing the 'tId'  number, for instance  1, lets call it tid (1)
2.  Want to compare tId (1)'s all milestones (except hypercareDate) with tid(1)'s forecastedDate milestone
3.  return if any of the milestone date (other than hypercareDate) is greater than the forecastedDate
The above 3 steps are simple, but I have to first compare the milestones date with its corresponding revised dates, if any, from the revised table,  and pick the max date among all that needs to be compared with the forecastedDate

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this.  Posting the answer, hope it helps aomebody.

```
//Insert the result into temp table
INSERT INTO @mstab
SELECT [mId]
        , [tId]
        , [msDate] 
    FROM [dbo].[MS]
    WHERE ([msName] NOT LIKE 'forecastedDate' AND [msName] NOT LIKE 'hypercareDate'))
// this scalar function will get max date between forecasted duedate and forecasted revised date    
SELECT @maxForecastedDate = [dbo].[fnGetMaxDate] ( 'forecastedDate');
// this will get the max date from temp table and compare it with forecasatedDate/
SET @maxmilestoneDate = (SELECT MAX(maxDate) 
                        FROM ( SELECT ms.msDueDate AS dueDate
                                     , mr.msRevisedDate AS revDate
                                FROM @mstab as ms 
                                    LEFT JOIN [MSRev] as mr on ms.msId = mr.msId
                             ) maxDate
                          UNPIVOT (maxDate FOR DateCols IN (dueDate, revDate))up );
```